# Drag down while sketching toggles layer?

Tags: krita

Sorry if it seems like a simple(stupid) question, but when I'm sketching or doing anything with a brush or any tool, Drag down, Drag up, Left, and Right all toggle my layers. it is a VERY annoying problem. I've searched for the answer but have found nothing. I looked in Krita settings and didn't find it there or on my tablet settings as well.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately I can't replicate the problem. How are you navigating around the document?  There are a couple of ways to move around a document while drawing, either use the Space bar and then drag, or use the centre mouse button to drag (or it's equivalent if you are using a graphics tablet).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was a Windows setting dealing with flicks. I turned flicks off in the Pen and Touch options.